# event display ends day before determined on fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, svelte

I'm trying to create an event.

```
calendarEvents = [
  ...calendarEvents,
  {
    title: 'New Event',
    start: currentDate,
    end: endDate,
    allDay: false
  },
];
```

But when the end of the event is set, in the display it ends one day before it's deadline. This is the config:

```
<div class="demo-app-calendar calendar">
    <FullCalendar bind:this={calendarComponentRef}
    defaultView="dayGridMonth"
minTime={"08:00:00"}
maxTime={"08:00:00"}
    droppable={true}
    editable={true}
    events={calendarEvents}
    header={{ left: 'prev,next today', center: 'title', right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek' }}
    height={800}
    plugins={plugins}
    weekends={calendarWeekends}
eventColor={'#000'}
nextDayThreshold={'00:09:00'}
    on:dateClick={(event) => handleDateClick(event)}
    />
</div>
```

[image]
[image]

I tried adding "nextDayThreshold", and altering it to "09:00:00","00:00:00:", and "00:09:00". When event was created i altered allDay to false and finally tried adding minmax time. But no result,can someone tell me how to make it work?

Comment: please show the exact event data you're using, otherwise we cannot know precisely what you mean. And please be aware that the end date/time of an event is **exclusive** (as per the documentation).

Comment: "finally tried adding minmax time"...these are irrelevant to your problem. They're just instructions about how to display the calendar itself, in the time grid view.

Comment: thank you for the comment. I didnt understand what you meant by exclusive?

Comment: Like I said, it''s described more clearly in the documentation. From https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object: _"end: 
Date object that obeys the current timeZone. When an event ends. It could be null if an end wasn’t specified.
**Note: This value is exclusive**. For example, an event with the end of 2018-09-03 will appear to span through 2018-09-02 but end before the start of 2018-09-03."_

Comment: Now i understood, thank you. But there is no way to change that? I searched and tryed the methods used in the git issues but none worked.they said to use the nextDaythreshold to change but it did not work.

Comment: As per the documentation, nextDayThreshold will only be used if your event has an end time (not just a date). Again, you need to show us the exact data you're using. You've shown us your event object, but it still relies on variables whose value we cannot see. Please show the precise start and end times of your event. These are clearly the most important and relevant pieces of data (especially the end date), yet you haven't provided them.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the further update. So yes, nextDayThreshold does not apply to your event, because it's an event with dates, but no specific times. If you really want the event to show on the calendar as crossing into the 16th then the workaround is to set the end date as the 17th.